# Кроссплатформенные приложения на Visual C++ 2010

Tags: кроссплатформенность, c++, visual-studio

Добрый день!
Интересует собственно сабж: с чего начинать, что нужно учесть и т.д. Был бы очень признателен за подробный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Выбрать подходящий кроссплатформенный фреймворк, к примеру [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products) или [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) или [GTK](http://gtk.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Начать нужно с изучения C++  :-).

Учесть нужно то, что нельзя использовать не кросс-платформенные библиотеки (вроде "windows.h") напрямую. Нужно использовать способы (например, [паттерн pointer to implementation](http://insidecpp.ru/patterns/pimpl_idiom/)), позволяющие для разных платформ подключать разные библиотеки.

Существуют кросс-платформенные библиотеки, например, `boost`.

Comment: Паттерны это не что-то особенное для С++, а программирование в целом кагбы

Comment: @AlexWindHope согласен

Answer (score 0):

На Visual C++ можно компилировать только под Windows. Можешь писать код в нём, но компилировать под другие платформы нужно будет на кроссплатформенном компиляторе, например, GCC. Использовать нужно только кроссплатформенные библиотеки. То есть для GUI - QT, GTK и др., для графики - OpenGL или какие-либо кроссплатформенные движки.

Можно использовать некроссплатформенные библиотеки, но придётся писать один и тот же код для разных платформ.